# Changing the mapStyle in Skobbler / Scout SDK

Tags: ios, skmaps

Im trying to change the map view style for my map. The code that I'm using is:

```
 SKMapViewStyle *mapViewStyle = [SKMapViewStyle mapViewStyle];
 mapViewStyle.resourcesFolderName = @"NightStyle";
 mapViewStyle.styleFileName = @"nightstyle.json";
 [SKMapView setMapStyle:mapViewStyle];
```

The app crashes when reaching this line: [SKMapView setMapStyle:mapViewStyle];

[image]

Comment: what version of the SDK are you using? (the latest available for download is 2.4) The code looks ok (the same as in the demo app) - did you modify in any way the SkMaps.bundle content?

Comment: I'm using ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK (2.4.0), I've installed it via CocoaPods and I haven't changed anything in SkMaps.bundle folder

Comment: can you a link to your project? we need more details to find the issue. Thanks